# Can someone help me understand the foreign key UPDATE and DELETE vs relationship name?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

Currently, I am working on the very beginnings of a user database in MySQL InnoDB. So, I will use that to help demonstrate.

```
    Users                       Roles
  ---------------              ---------------
  userid (bigint) PK          >roleid (tinyint) PK
  email  (varchar)             rolename (varchar)
  username (varchar)
  password (char)
 >roleid (tinyint) FK
  created (timestamp)
```

Right now, I am trying to create a one-to-many relationship between Role and Users, based on roleid. For this, I am thinking that `On UPDATE` `CASCADE` and `On DELETE` `Restrict`.

That's what I feel like I should do, I'm not sure if it's correct or not. However, I'd like to gain a better understanding of it.

Say I wanted to created one-to-one, then that would look like `On UPDATE` `Restrict` and `On DELETE` `Restrict`, is that correct?

Sorry, I am completely confused here and I am unable to find a tutorial, blog, or explanation that breaks down the different settings to the Relational Model. Could anyone help explain it these types as well as the other types (many-to-many, many-to-one) based on what I have here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One role can have many users associated to that role. This *entire* relationship is represented physically with a `foreign key` on the USERS table that references the ROLES table.

The `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` options in the foreign key constraint help to enforce "referential integrity" in the database, but they don't specify at all what the relationship is between the USERS and ROLES entities.

If I create this foreign key with ON DELETE RESTRICT, when I would try to delete a record from the ROLES table where the key was in use on the USERS table, i would get an error. *This has nothing to do with the type of logical relationship that exists - it is just a constraint*.

A many to many relationship cannot be modeled using one foreign key. Logically, if A user can have Many Roles, storing the role id on the users table doesn't make sense.

In that case, you would create a table in between, and put the userid and roleid columns on this table, with foreign keys connecting them to users and roles respectively.

```
USERS         USERS_ROLES     ROLES
userid PK  -  userid FK    
              roleid FK   -   roleid PK
```

[Here's the MYSQL manual pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) about foreign key constraints. It's a good reference and explains what each option means.

Edit:

This touched on the one-to-many and many-to-many relationship types. Rarely will you see a one-to-one type in a database (in those cases merging the tables makes sense). Sometimes for performance you would use it. In these cases, typically your primary key should be the same on both tables:

```
USERS             USERS_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES
userid PK    -    userid PK FK
```

Only 1 user id should exist on each table for a 1-1 relationship.